# Wrong file extension added in image byte array

Tags: c#, arrays, .net

I have a method that takes a web-based image, converts it into a byte array and then passes that to a CDN as an image.

I have now used this successfully hundreds of times, however on migrating a particular set of images, I've noticed that these Jpeg files are identifying as .png files which when they arrive at the CDN are blank.

Using some code that I copied from the web, I am able to identify the file extension from the image byte array after it is built.

So, it's the conversion from the original image to byte array that is mysteriously updating the file type.

This is my method:-

```
public byte[] Get(string fullPath)
{
  byte[] imageBytes = { };
  var imageRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(fullPath);
  var imageResponse = imageRequest.GetResponse();

  var responseStream = imageResponse.GetResponseStream();

  if (responseStream != null)
  {
    using (var br = new BinaryReader(responseStream))
    {
      imageBytes = br.ReadBytes(500000);
      br.Close();
    }
    responseStream.Close();
   }
            
   imageResponse.Close();
   return imageBytes;
}
```

I have also tried converting this to use MemoryStream instead.

I'm not sure what else I can do to ensure that this identifies the correct file type.

**Edit**

I have now updated the number of allowed bytes which has resulted in viable images.

However the issue with the JPEG files being altered to PNG is still ongoing.

It's only this selection of images that are affected.
These images were saved in an old CMS system so I do wonder if the way that they were saved is the cause?

Comment: Are the images larger than 500,000 bytes?

Comment: Good question. The file sizes are each 488kb.

Comment: please present a [mre].

Comment: _The file sizes are each 488kb_ Well that is too close, with a little rounding it is over the amount you read.

Comment: "too close" is good... that, 488 KiB, is _exactly_ what happens when files are truncated to 500 kB. 500e3 / 2**10 == 488.28125. smells like the files were already truncated, or OP looked at the results, not the inputs.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz You are quite right. I did look at the results. The originals were 780kb. Markus pointed me in the right direction and I increased the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up to now, the code only reads 500,000 bytes for each file. If the file is larger than that, the end is truncated and the content is not valid anymore. In order to read all bytes, you can use the following code:

```
public byte[] Get(string fullPath)
{
  List<byte> imageBytes = new List<byte>(500000);
  var imageRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(fullPath);
  using (var imageResponse = imageRequest.GetResponse())
  {
    using (var responseStream = imageResponse.GetResponseStream())
    {
      using (var br = new BinaryReader(responseStream))
      {
        var buffer = new byte[500000];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = br.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) > 0)
        {
          imageBytes.AddRange(buffer);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return imageBytes.ToArray();
}
```

Above sample reads the data in chunks of 500,000 bytes - for most of your files, this should be sufficient. If a file is larger, the code reads more chunks until there are no more bytes to read. All the chunks are assembled in a list.

This asserts that all the bytes are read, even if the content is larger than 500,000 bytes.

Comment: Thank you for the example.
Whilst the code you kindly supplied didn't solve the issue as such, I did take onboard your earlier comment and manually upped the count to 5,000,000 which is at least resulting in an image, although still a .png
I know that's probably not ideal!, but this isn't production code - its used in migrating content and will be disposed of once that task is over.